# What is the difference between "sequence" and "string"?

Tags: c++, c

for example.

mbtowc vs. mbstowcs (stdlib.h)
mbrtowc vs. mbsrtowc (wchar.h)

What is the difference between "sequence" and "string"?

In addition,
I'd like to know how to use mbstate_t of mbrtowc/mbsrtowc in an example.

Comment: All of these functions are fully documented by their respective manual pages. What exactly in their documentation do you need help with understanding?

Comment: size_t mbstowcs (wchar_t* dest, const char* src, size_t max); / int mbtowc (wchar_t* pwc, const char* pmb, size_t max); ... two functions accept the same parameters, and I want to know the difference of the parameters.

Comment: [wchar.h](pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/wchar.h.html) 
 [stdlib.h](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/stdlib.h.html)  and [this](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Keeping-the-state.html).

Comment: Well, as you know, both `strcpy()` and `strcat()` have the "same parameters", a `char *`, and a `const char *`. But they do different things, and to understand the difference between the two, you have to read their documentation. Same thing here. The two functions do different things. You need to read their documentation to find out what is the difference between the two. If you do not understand something in the documentation of either function, then you can ask a specific question, but nobody here is going to simply copy-and-paste both manual pages as your answer.

Comment: `mbtowc` converts a *single* character

Comment: I got the clear answer, thanks @vu1p3n0x and R..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C, a "string" is defined as an array (possibly a subarray of a larger array) of `char` ending with the null character. The multibyte *string* functions operate on strings, processing multibyte characters until they reach the end of the string (or run out of space in the destination buffer).

The multibyte character functions that operate on "sequences" of bytes (`char`s) convert only a single multibyte character at a time (or, in the case of `mbrtowc`, possibly even less). There is no requirement that the input `char` array be a string.

Comment: you mean, the functions handling "string" convert characters until they meet NULL character and the ones handling "sequence" convert just one character?

Comment: Concerning _string_ definition, why not use the specified one: "A _string_ is a contiguous sequence of characters terminated by and including the first null character."  Unclear why "an array (possibly a subarray of a larger array) " was chosen?